# Can you create subsystems in a Function Block Diagram (FBD) in PLC programming?

Tags: plc

My Function Block Diagrams are becoming unwieldy.

I am trying to subsystem them by using memory elements for input/output ports to break the diagrams into sub-diagrams.

Is there a more standard way to do this?

Comment: Not an expert in PLC, but doesn't it depend on the software being used?

Comment: Which PLC are you using?

Comment: thanks @BenMiller-RememberMonica, for now I'm just experimenting with Control/IO from https://realgames.co/ -- I guess my question was a bit naive, I figured FBD has standardized semantics say like C++